# How to round the List of decimal values?

Tags: c#

Can you please explain how to format my list of decimal to two decimal places & the total should be 100.00?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string decimalFormat = "0.00";
        decimal[] individuals = { 10, 10, 10 };
        decimal total = 30;
        List<decimal> percents = new List<decimal>();
        foreach (decimal t in individuals)
        {
            decimal percent = (t * 100) / total;
            percents.Add(percent);
        }

        List<decimal> roundToTwoDecimalPercent = new List<decimal>();
        foreach (decimal portfolio in percents)
        {
            roundToTwoDecimalPercent.Add(Math.Round(portfolio, 2));
        }

        decimal percentTotal = decimal.Zero;
        foreach (decimal final in roundToTwoDecimalPercent)
        {
            percentTotal += final;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(percentTotal.ToString(decimalFormat)); // 99.99 but the EXPECTED OUTPUT IS 100.00
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Thanks,
S.Venkatesh

Answer (score 5):

Basically,

> The sum of rounded figures is not necessarily equal the rounded sum of the same figures.

You need to only round once, at the end.

This will give you your expected output:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string decimalFormat = "0.00";
    decimal[] individuals = { 10, 10, 10 };
    decimal total = 30;
    List<decimal> percents = new List<decimal>();
    foreach (decimal t in individuals)
    {
        decimal percent = (t * 100) / total;
        percents.Add(percent);
    }

    decimal percentTotal = decimal.Zero;
    foreach (decimal percent in percents)
    {
        percentTotal += percent;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N2}", percentTotal)); 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**OR:** if you're a LINQ-fan like myself, this will give you the same result:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    decimal[] individuals = { 10, 10, 10 };

    decimal total = individuals.Sum();

    decimal[] percentages = individuals.Select(i => i * 100 / total).ToArray();

    decimal percentageTotal = percentages.Sum();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N2}", percentageTotal));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Additional Example**: Using the following test app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    decimal[] individuals = { 10, 10, 10 };

    Console.WriteLine("Unrounded figures");

    var percentages = individuals.Select(i => i * 100 / individuals.Sum()).ToList();

    percentages.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

    decimal percentageTotal = percentages.Sum();
    Console.WriteLine("Their unrounded sum = {0}", percentageTotal);
    Console.WriteLine("Their rounded sum = {0:N2}", percentageTotal);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Rounded figures");

    var roundedPercentages = individuals.Select(i => Math.Round(i * 100 / individuals.Sum(), 2)).ToList();
    roundedPercentages.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

    decimal roundedPercentageTotal = roundedPercentages.Sum();

    Console.WriteLine("Their unrounded sum = {0}", roundedPercentageTotal);
    Console.WriteLine("Their rounded sum = {0:N2}", roundedPercentageTotal);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I get the following output:

[image: output]

Comment: Do I want to show the list of decimal [each percent i.e 33.33] as two decimal places then It will not equal to 100%

Comment: Obviously not. When you calculate the sum, work with the **unrounded** figures - then when you round the result, it will will be calculated correctly. The rule of thumb is, don't work with rounded figures when you are doing calculations. Only round figures when you are **presenting** them to the user.

Comment: @user1531248: See my updated answer. I posted an example showing the difference when you're dealing with rounded and unrounded figures.